# How to make Page Inspector respect X-UA-Compatible (Compatibility View Mode)?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, page-inspector

My team have a legacy project where we use the `X-UA-Compatible` tag to garantee *Internet Explorer* render the page in [Compatibility View Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#DCMODES) **since we need to support IE7** and beyong.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
```

It works in IE but the [Page Inpector](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/ASP-NET-Site-Videos/Visual-Studio-2013-Web-Editor-Features-Page-Inspector) in *Visual Studio 2013* render the page like it renders in IE with standard *Document Mode* instead.

We can only troubleshoot the problem with this compatibility in place since it does not occur in standard mode.

There is any configuration or hack to make *Page Inspector* renders the page in *Compatibility Mode*?

Answer (score 1):

No there is no hack or configuration to make Page Inspector renders the page in compat mode.

Comment: I know it's not easy but do you have any source about `Page Inspector` compatibility?